# How can i convert decimal to ternary?

Tags: c#

I already tried:

```
Convert.ToString(123, 3);
```

but that gives me a `System.ArgumentException: Invalid Base`

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg [Not just](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this standard algorithm:

```
public static String ToTrenary(int value) {
  if (value == 0)
    return "";

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
  Boolean signed = false;

  if (value < 0) {
    signed = true; 
    value = -value;
  }

  while (value > 0) {
    Sb.Insert(0, value % 3);
    value /= 3;
  }

  if (signed)
    Sb.Insert(0, '-');

  return Sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Won't that `Insert` put numbers before the negative sign?